# Convert Pajek file to CSV in R Shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny, igraph

Does anyone know how to read pajek file in shiny and then find the degree of each vertex and output it to CSV file in descending order? I'm not sure how to take the file from filedata() method where it reads the graph, then take it's degree of the pajek file then output them in CSV file where highest degree is at the top and lowest at the bottom.

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/got76j05yygmxka/network.net?dl=0) the Pajek file i want to import in and export the degree into CSV.

In R, i know how to code it normally like this:

```
#read the pajek file in igraph
reponetwork <- read.graph("network.net", format = "pajek")

#Inspect the data:
degree(reponetwork)
sort(degree(reponetwork), decreasing = TRUE)
```

But I'm not sure how to do it in Shiny:

Here's what I've done so far:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Finding most influential vertex in a network"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

     fileInput("graph", label = h4("Pajek file")),

      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

    ),
    mainPanel( tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                           tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("view")) 

                           ) 

               )

  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(igraph)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2) 

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    filedata <- reactive({
      inFile = input$graph
      if (!is.null(inFile))
      data <- read.graph(file=inFile$datapath, format="pajek")
      return(data)
    })

  #get the pajek file, get the degree from it using degree(),
  #display the output(only degree with respect to vertex ids) in the view tab panel
   output$view <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(filedata())) {
    return()
  }
  df <- filedata()
  vorder <-sort(degree(df), decreasing=TRUE)
  DF <- data.frame(ID=as.numeric(V(df)[vorder]), degree=degree(df)[vorder])
})

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste(input$graph, '.csv', sep='')
  },

  # Not sure how to write to csv file 
  content = function(file) {
  write.csv(DF, file)
      } 

    )
      })
```

and the desired CSV file columns should have: 1. Vertex id
2. Degree of that vertex

Comment: In R shiny you have the same functionality as in R, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is im not sure how to get the file as a variable so i can use in my degree() function. And they don't allow me to use the data variable that i've written in read.graph() line and received error message: "Not a graph object" @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: since your data variable is global (which you achieved by using <<- ) you could try to write df<-data (I am not sure this will work) - or even better write return(data) in the function filedata(). Than you would not need to make it global.

Comment: I've edited my question with the `return(data)` but i still received an error saying "Error in degree(df) : Not a graph object" do you know why? @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: it's hard for me to debug because I don't have all your methods and data, but we can do it together :) please add: print(str(df)) after df<-filedata() and if you still have your old code from above also try print(str(reponetwork)) than we'll see what's different.

Comment: My data is in the link i've written above, and my methods are just to export csv(only degree column with respect to vertex ids) from my pajek file(in the link) in Shiny. Thank you for your help tho :) @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: When i `print(str(df))` after df <- filedata() it shows "function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE)" on browser mode. But when i `print(str(reponetwork))` it has no error and shows the edges @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: I've added some comments on my code. Please take a look. @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your file. I'll check it out.

Comment: Do you have a smaller sample file? It takes really long to test.

Comment: [Open this] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/t84i7kf8lb5dy6x/Rnetwork.net?dl=0) here's the smaller file. Sorry about that. @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: Sorry I don't have much time to test it extensively and so far it didn't work... I think the problem is the fileInput, which directly uploads it. If you print inFile$datapath you will see it is some temp file. You could check out file.choose() which just returns the path. Check out if it works for you and I can help you to make it look like fileInput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you've tried or what hasn't worked for you, but this should do it:

```
g <-read.graph(file=inFile$datapath, format='pajek')
vorder <- order(degree(g), decreasing=TRUE)
DF <- data.frame(ID=as.numeric(V(g)[vorder]), degree=degree(g)[vorder])
write.csv(DF, file='foo.txt')
```

Comment: that would be easy in normal R. but im not sure how to do it in R Shiny? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Try returning the graph object using the `<<-` operator.

Comment: where do i put this at? in filedata()?

Comment: I've edited my server.R like this `output$view <- renderTable({
      vorder <- order(degree(data), decreasing=TRUE)
      DF <- data.frame(ID=V(data)[vorder], degree=degree(data)[vorder])
    
      
    })` but i received an error saying "Not a graph object" when i put `data <<-read.graph(file=inFile$datapath, format='pajek')`

Comment: If i do if normally in R with your codes, it says that i can't coerce "igraph" to data frame. Do you know?

Comment: Try `ID=as.numeric(V(g)[vorder])`, if the vertex names are numbers as opposed to character strings.

Comment: Done thank you! Hey, btw how do I find the betweenness of each vertex and sort it the same like in degree? @Chris

Comment: Do you mean betweenness centrality? You can just substitute `centr_betw` instead of `degree` in your code.

Comment: What's the difference between `betweenness()` and `centr_betw()` ? @Chris

Comment: They're the same thing

Comment: how do i find out clustering coefficient (or transitivity) of **each vertex** ? I used `transitivity` function but it does not do for each vertex @Chris

Comment: If you continue to have issues, you should open a new question, or use the igraph help mailing list, and check out the vignettes and tutorials available for igraph.